# String Manipulation - Removing the charachters of the second word to the first word

Tags: java

Enter two words: computer program

result: cute

`the character of the second word of the users input is deleted on the first word of the input in java. Leaving "cute"`
 thought of using replaceAll but could not make it work.

```
    String sentence;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 2 words: ");
    sentence = input.nextLine();

    String[] arrWrd = sentence.split(" ");

    String scdWrd = arrWrd[1];

    String fnl = arrWrd[0].replaceAll(scdWrd, "");

    System.out.println(fnl);
```

Comment: Just to not drive you away: I didnt want to belittle you or so. But as I wrote: this place isn't about "teaching" in the broader sense. Newbies are welcome to ask questions here, too. But it is expected that you do some sort of research upfront. And these very basic language things ... are better explained in books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.replaceAll` takes a regex, so basically what you are doing here is you're searching for the whole "program" word and replacing it and not its characters, so you just need to add brackets to your scdWrd to let it know that you want to replace the chars:

```
String scdWrd = "[" + arrWrd[1] + "]";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the elegant solution by @B.Mik, you should also check for things like

1. If multiple spaces are entered between the words.
2. If the user enters a blank line or just one word e.g. execute your program and enter a blank line or just one word e.g. `computer` and you will be welcomed with `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The program given below addresses these points:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LettersFromSecondReplacement {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean valid;
        String input;
        String words[];
        do {
            valid = true;
            System.out.print("Enter two words separated with space: ");
            input = in.nextLine();
            words = input.split("\\s+"); //Split on one or more spaces
            if (words.length != 2) {
                System.out.println("Error: wrong input. Try again");
                valid = false;
            }
        } while (!valid);
        for (String s : words[1].split("")) { //Split the 2nd word into strings of one character
            words[0] = words[0].replaceAll(s, "");
        }

        System.out.println(words[0]);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter two words separated with space: 
Error: wrong input. Try again
Enter two words separated with space: computer
Error: wrong input. Try again
Enter two words separated with space: computer program
cute
```

Note that I have used a different algorithm (which you can replace with the one provided by @B.Mik) for replacement. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue

Answer (score 0):

replace line with replaceAll by

```
    String fnl = arrWrd[0];
    for (byte c : scdWrd.getBytes()) {
        fnl = fnl.replace("" + (char)c, "");
    }
```